# Custom IPrincipal together with WindowsAuthentication

Tags: asp.net, authentication, windows-authentication

Is there any good way of combining ASP.NET Windows Authentication with a custom IPrincipal/IIdentity object? I need to store the user's email address and have done so for Forms Authentication using a custom IIdentity/IPrincipal pair that I added to the Context.CurrentUser during the AuthenticateRequest event.

How would I best go by to accomplish this using WindowsAuthentication?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you could create your "ExtendedWindowsPrincipal" as a derived class based on WindowsPrincipal, and just add your extra data to the derived class?

That way, your ExtendedWindowsPrincipal would still be recognized anywhere where a WindowsPricinpal is needed.

OR: since you're talking about using Windows Authentication, you're probably in a Windows network - is there an Active Directory or a user database somewhere, where you could look up your e-mail address that you're interested in instead of storing it in the principal?

Marc

Comment: Creating a derived class was my idea, but I'm unsure on if it's wise to replace the IPrincipal and how it's done correctly.

I intent to lookup the email address from the directory, but my idea was to collect all user information in one place, just like I have done w. custom authentication.

Comment: I don't see any problem replacing a WindowsPrincipal by your own ExtendedWindowsPrincipal, if it's a derived class. After all, it's still a WindowsPrincipal - with some added stuff.
To do it, I would investigate the global.asax and the Application_AuthenticateRequest.

Comment: I got problems with trying to get the IsInRole to still work and didn't want to invest the time into using IPrincipal, so I ended up putting the rest of the user information in the context items. 

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3):

I ended up refactoring my initial solution into replacing the Principal instead of the Identity as I originally thought. Replacing the Identity proved troublesome, since i ran into security problems when creating an instance of a new extended WindowsPrincipal.

```
public class ExtendedWindowsPrincipal : WindowsPrincipal
{
    private readonly string _email;

    public ExtendedWindowsPrincipal(WindowsIdentity ntIdentity, 
       string email) : base(ntIdentity)
    {
            _email = email;
    }

    public string Email
    {
        get { return _email; }
    }
}
```

In my Authentication module i replaced the principal on the HttpContext like this:

```
var currentUser = (WindowsIdentity)HttpContext.Current.User.Identity;
HttpContext.Current.User = 
    new ExtendedWindowsPrincipal(currentUser, userEmail);
```

Comment: thanks for the post, been banging my head for a few hours now. Ran into the same security problems...wtf! right? Your solution work though, many thanks!